# How do I convert from an ArrayList to a cli::array?

Tags: .net, arraylist, c++-cli

How can I convert from a `System::Collections::ArrayList` (containing `System::String^` for example) to an array of `cli::array<String^>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the ArrayList is in your code and you can change it, consider changing it to a `List<String^>`. You'll get type safety, cleaner code when using the class, more available Linq methods, and the normal builtin method on that class will return an `array<String^>` without having to jump through any hoops.

---

There's a builtin method on ArrayList to do this for you. Call ToArray, and specify the type of the array to be returned.

```
ArrayList^ list = ...;
array<String^>^ ar = reinterpret_cast<array<String^>^>(list->ToArray(String::typeid));
```

If you're doing this with other collection types (that aren't using generics), you'll have to do something more manual. You could do it by hand:

```
ArrayList^ list = ...;
array<String^>^ ar = gcnew array<String^>(list.Count);
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    ar[i] = dynamic_cast<String^>(list[i]);
```

Or you could use Linq to convert the ArrayList to an `IEnumerable<String^>`, and then convert that to an array of strings.

```
ArrayList^ list = ...;
array<String^> ar = Enumerable::ToArray(Enumerable::OfType<String^>(list));
```

Comment: reinterpret_cast was copied directly from MSDN. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcyyh2hb.aspx and click C++ for the language.

Comment: Okay, ignore that.  Gotta get the OP to use `List<String^>`.

Comment: Quite right, converting to `List<String^>` would be much better. Edited.